# Tooltips for a SVG photo that work on an iPad

Tags: css, svg, tooltip

I have a svg photo on the page at https://bullittcountyhistory.org/1974centennial/crowdview.html that uses the title code for a tooltip to identify each person's face when hovering over it. It works fine except on a mobile device like the iPad.

I've also found at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp css tooltip code that works on the iPad as well as my computer.

Is there any way to tie the two together, creating tooltips that show up on the iPad? I've spent the last two days searching the internet for clues, but no one seems to have figured this out (that I can see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would basically do the same thing, except you would use SVG elements, instead of HTML ones.

However I don't have an iPad, so I can't vouch for whether it works on one.

```css
.tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

.tooltiptext text {
  fill: #fff;
}

.tooltiptext rect {
  fill: black;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg>

  <g class="tooltip">
    <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="75" fill="red"/>

    <g class="tooltiptext">
      <rect x="90" y="62" width="120" height="1.4em" rx="6"/>
      <text x="150" y="75" dy="0.4em" text-anchor="middle">Tooltip text</text>
    </g>
  </g>
  
</svg>
```